# Doubt on an ODE problem

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the following differential equation

$$x'(t) = h(x(t))$$

Consider a function $x(t)$ which satisfies the differential equation for $0 \lt t \leq 1$ and another function $y(t)$ for $0.5 \leq t \leq 2$. Then define $$ z(t) = x(t) 0 \lt t \leq 1; z(t) = y(t) 0.5 \leq t \leq 2; x(t) = y(t)  0.5\leq t \leq 1 $$. Then, is not this obvious that $z(t)$ satisfies the differential equation for $0 < t \leq 2$. I see that a book proves this transforming the ODE into an integral equation. It says that it needs to check the continuity of $z'(t)$ at $t=1$. What is the need for it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is tacitly assumed that the function $h: \>{\mathbb R}\to{\mathbb R}$ is locally Lipschitz-continuous. It follows that any solution of the ODE
$$x'(t)=h\bigl(x(t)\bigr)\tag{1}$$
is $C^1$ throughout its interval of definition. When
$$t\mapsto x(t) \quad(0<t<1),\qquad t\mapsto y(t)\quad(0.5<t<2)$$
are two particular solutions of $(1)$, found by whichever means, then two possibilities arise: Either $x(0.75)=y(0.75)$, or $x(0.75)\ne y(0.75)$. In the first case $x(\cdot)$ and $y(\cdot)$ belong to the *same* "maximal solution" of $(1)$, and coincide wherever both are defined, i.e., on the interval$\>]0.5, 1[\>$. In the second case $x(\cdot)$ and $y(\cdot)$ are genuinely different solutions of $(1)$, and it is impossible to paste them together to a single solution $z(\cdot)$.

Comment: Sir, thanks for the reply. But, under lipschitz condition the trajectories will be same in the common portion. I was going through the material http://nptel.ac.in/courses/111104031/ (page 23 middle). If possible, please check. Thanks in advance Sir.